# D3 Tip not working when loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js

I'm using $.get to load a D3 chart via AJAX. It grabs the HTML and script tag inserts it into the page and runs the JS.

Everything works as expected except for the D3 Tip functionality.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```js
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<b>" + d.value + "</b> - " +  (Math.round( d.count / total * 100)) + "%";
    });

var svg = d3.select("#histogram").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
<?php if($timeline == 'manual') : ?>
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value) + ", 0)"; })
<?php else: ?>
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (x(d.value) - (bar_width / 2)) + ", 0)"; })
<?php endif; ?>
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);\
```

**Note:** I did some testing and the `.on('mouseover')` function is being called, so it's `tip.show` that's not working.

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: @DamienFayol - None unfortunately :/